# python cx_oracle cursor.rowcount returning 0 but cursor.fetchall returns data

Tags: python, sql, database, oracle11g, cx-oracle

I have this code where I am executing a `select sql` statement from `python` code using `cx_oracle` package:

```
import cx_Oracle

try:
    cur = conn.cursor()
    result = cur.execute('select * from table1')
    print(str(cur.rowcount))
    print(cur.fetchall())

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

When I execute the above code I see `0` coming in for `cur.rowcount` but I see following data getting printed for `cur.fetchall()`:

```
[('185',), ('1860',), ('1908',)]
```

[cx_Oracle package documentation](http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cursor.html#Cursor.rowcount) does mention `Cursor.rowcount` as a valid operation so I am not sure why in my code it is returning `0` even though the data is coming?

Comment: What if you `print(str(cur.rowcount))` __after__ `print(cur.fetchall())`?

Comment: @CristiFati Yes then it does print. Why is this behavior? Is it the requirement in cx_Oracle package? In pymysql package it doesn't need to be this way

Comment: I've never used _cx\_Oracle_ (at least not directly). But, quote from the doc (link you provided): "_This read-only attribute specifies the number of rows that **have currently been fetched** from the cursor ..._". Regarding _pyMySQL_, I know nothing of that either, but they are 2 separate packages wrapping 2 different _DB_ systems.... I don't think there's any restriction for them to behave the same way.

Answer (score 8):

The documentation states that cursor.rowcount specifies the number of rows that have currently been fetched. Immediately after the cursor.execute() call has been made, no rows have been fetched, so the result is 0. If you call cursor.fetchone() then result will be 1 and if you call cursor.fetchmany(5), then the result will be 6, and so forth (assuming there are enough rows to satisfy your requests, of course!).

Answer (score 6):

[cx-oracle.readthedocs](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_manual/cursor.html#Cursor.rowcount) mentioned Cursor.rowcount specified number of rows affected by insert, update and delete statement. You are using a select statement.

```
cur.execute('select * from table1')
result = cur.fetchall()
print (len(result)) # this will return number of records affected by select statement
print (result)
```

Comment: I don't think thats true. The document says `This read-only attribute specifies the number of rows that have currently been fetched from the cursor (for select statements)`

Comment: Your question is explained here: [link] (https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_oracle/issues/16/cursorrowcount-is-not-populated-after-dql)